# Detach subscription/web socket updates in some ngrx form controls

Tags: angular, graphql, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms, apollo-client

I am using Angular 7 with NGRX.

I have an angular container component which has 2 child components.
The container passes the stream as input to his child components ("value$ | async").

In the child component, I have ngrx form that shows the object properties.

**Problem:**

I want to mark some of the properties as editable and disable subscription updates,
in addition - I want some of them to get updates from the server.

container.html:

```
<div class="table-row-item">
  <app-row-item [valueInput]="value$ | async"></app-row-item>
</div>
<div class="form">
  <app-form [valueInput]="value$.value"></app-item>
</div>
```

app-form.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="value">
    <form name="singleValueForm" novalidate [formGroup]="formGroup" [connectForm]="value">
        <input disabled type="text" formControlName="source" /> <!-- Get update from server -->
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" /> <!-- Don't get update from server -->
    </form>
</ng-container>
```